# Trouble creating a RAID setup with my Flashdrives

Tags: raid, usb-flash-drive

I have been trying to get my RAID to work with my 2 16Gb flash-drives but it does not want to work. For what I have no clue. What are the steps that you have done to get yours working, because maybe I am doing something wrong? And if there is a free software for windows 8.1 that makes it a snap then PLEASE paste a link on. And if could explain how to use it. This is for a RAID 0 setup. I do plan on doing a RAID 1 in the near future.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We will be able to help you only if you can provide us with more details... What kinds of drives are they? How are they formatted? What have you tried?

Comment: They are normall flash drives you would get at the store, mine are 2.0. FAT32, can convert to NTFS. I ave tried both